# Ethos 1.3.0 drops hashrate on RX 560 4GB card

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, mining, ethminer, ethos

After upgrading my Ethos to 1.3.0 from 1.2.9, the `hashrate` of RX 560 becomes very low. Initially there was `gpu clock problem` error. After playing with the `flags` in `local.conf`, I was able to get rid of the error. Here is the config I end up with:

```
flags --cl-global-work 16384 --farm-recheck 300
```

But the hashrate of 4 `RX 560` cards is very low. It was `10.5mh` before. But it is only `2.21 - 7.76mh`:

```
  ¹  13:03:45|ethminer   Accepted.
  m  13:03:45|ethminer  Speed   2.21 Mh/s    gpu/0  2.21  [A2+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:14
  m  13:03:46|ethminer  Speed   7.65 Mh/s    gpu/0  7.65  [A6+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:14
  m  13:03:46|ethminer  Speed   7.13 Mh/s    gpu/0  7.13  [A6+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:14
  m  13:03:46|ethminer  Speed   7.76 Mh/s    gpu/0  7.76  [A5+0:R0+0:F0] Time: 00:14
```

The motherboard is `ASUS EX-B250-V7` 6 GPU with latest BIOS. What are the parameters I need to adjust to have normal hashrate on RX 560? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Installing Fixes on the Latest ethOS Version` on page http://ethosdistro.com/kb/#updating-miners provides fixes for both AMD and NV GPU on ETHOS 1.3.0 and improved the hashrate. Just following the instruction on the page.